# create a model odoo12 with intermediate tables

Tags: odoo-12

I'm starting to learn Odoo and I'm developing an application in **Odoo 12**. I want to represent a database with intermediate table, in this case I have 2 tables ( products and actions ) and the relationship is 1...n and I must have an intermediate table that joins two tables.

```
Product (id, name, price...) 
Action (id, name) 
Product_action (id, id_product, id_action, date_from, date_to)
```

How I can do this? How can i represent this in the Odoo's model?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a model for the intermediate. You can also represent the entries of this intermediate model (rows in table) as 1:n relation on both the other models:

```py
class ProductAction(models.Model):
    _name = "product.action"

    date_from = fields.Date()
    date_to = fields.Date()
    product_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="product.product")
    action_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="action.model.name")

class ProductProduct(models.Model):
    _inherit = "product.product"

    intermediate_ids = fields.One2many(
        comodel_name="product.action", inverse_name="product_id")

class ActionClassName(models.Model):
    _inherit = "action.model.name"

    intermediate_ids = fields.One2many(
        comodel_name="product.action", inverse_name="action_id")
```

I assumed you are using Odoo's product class `product.product` but don't know what class/model is used for "actions" so i used a wildcard name for it in my example code.

Comment: thanks for the help i will try this solution for now, i'm not using the Odoo's product class but it is similar :)